# Can't use TerminateProcess with msys2 on Win7

Tags: windows, winapi, gtk3, msys2

I'm making in gtk3 app that behaves like a launcher. I'm developing in linux and windows7 with msys2 and msvc2010. Everyhing is fine except that I can't use **TerminateProcess** because I get this warning:

```
implicit declaration of function 'TerminateProcess'
```

This is part of the code:

```
#if defined(G_OS_WIN32)
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#include <w32api.h>
#define WINVER WindowsXP
#define _WIN32_WINNT WindowsXP
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS WindowsXP
#define _WIN32_IE IE7
#endif
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#endif
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// ...

void kill_process (GPid pid)
{
#if defined(G_OS_WIN32)
    TerminateProcess (pid, 0);
#else
    kill (pid, SIGTERM);
#endif
    g_spawn_close_pid (pid);
}
```

The above function **kill_process** works as expected in linux and in windows (msvc 2010), but it doesn't with msys2 mingw64... any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `<processthreadsapi.h>` directly, instead of using `<windows.h>`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, either way.. has the same effect.

Comment: Have a look at mingw's `processthreadsapi.h`. `TerminateProcess` definition is surrounded by a `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION (WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)` condition, so you must define that.

Comment: MinGW needs to be actively maintained. In lieu thereof, people just need to stop using MinGW. The latter seems to be the more pragmatic solution.